# How to find which column in a table in a database has an '!' exclamation mark.

Tags: sql

Say I have a table 'Tablex' in a database DB1, with diff columns column1, column2, ...etc columnx one of these columns has data with an exclamation mark say for example 'Durian!Tex'

what is the query to find which table in which db has a column which contains a value '%!%'

This is to search the whole database to give out the Db name, Table Name, column name . Hope My question is clear.

Comment: export the whole database to .sql file and find it by using cntrl+F :)

Comment: It's a sign that your data model is broken if you have *multiple* columns that contain the same "type" of data, such that it makes sense to write queries that want to treat all of those columns the same - it's an indication that they should in fact *be* a single column - and that alongside that column, there ought to be other columns that contain the *data* that has somehow ended up becoming embedded in column or table names.

Comment: if not for a special character...to know which cell has a value 'abc' that also we cant find?

Answer (score 0):

export the whole database to `.sql` file and find it by using **cntrl+F**

And `replace/remove` it whatever you want

and `import it` to the new database

Comment: Unable to export the database ...its a huge database...how can we do that?

Comment: @Srupts are you using any UI?

Answer (score 0):

I have found one store procedure from the internet when i was looking for same thing. You can use following SP to find text/Character in all the columns in the tables.

First run the SP and then execute the sp using EXEC and search the character in parameter value.

```
--EXEC SearchAllTables '!'

CREATE PROC SearchAllTables
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                               ) = 0
        )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                    AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END 
    END

    SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
END
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Srupts  Then you can use simple query which is inside the SP. Copy that Script and run it separately with search parameter. If you want then i can help you to write that script without using create new sp.